# How to save a nested associative array with different keys on each level in RDBMS?

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures, tree, nested-loops

I have a response coming in `JSON` which is converted to associative `array` in `php` (Wordpress).

I want to save it in different `table`s, this structure is about 9 levels deep and have different `key`s on each level, tried doing it with `foreach` but it causes about 5 nested loops to get the deepest values.

It is a related structure so each nested array needs `foreign key` from its parent array when saved in DB.

Here is an excerpt from it.

```php
array(
    'data' => array(
        0 => array(
            'p_a' => array(
                1 => array(
                    'child' => array(
                        254 => array(
                            'b_c' => array(
                                'm' => array(
                                    'c' => array(
                                        'USD' => array(
                                            'price' => '0.99',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

So each level has multiple `key`s but I have only included the nested ones, and each *named* key can have multiple `array`s like with `'p_a'`, it can have multiple `array`s which contain `'child'` `array`, I don't know beforehand the indexes like in `data` it could start from 1 or 0 but don't know how many child will it contain. Similarly for other nested ones.

I have tried saving them in other `array`s to simplify it but it still complicates it, I thought about `recursion` but I think it would create many `if`s for each level as they are not same on each level.

What could be a good `data-structure` to convert this to? I thought trees but each `node` is different and I don't know any good tree structures which can help in this?

**EDIT** I'm doing bulk `insert`s so I would want to save the parents first then children but if DFS is the only way then maybe I'll do one by one.

**EDIT** How I want to insert rows from above data

`data`

```sql
id | attributes ...
```

`p_a`

```sql
id | data_id | attributes ...
```

`child`

```sql
id | p_a_id | attributes ...
```

`b_c`

```sql
id | child_id | attributes ...
```

Comment: Could you provide something like desired result?

Comment: I would want to convert this into something which I can iterate without nesting and fetch values to save in DB like flattening the arrays but then I have to keep track of which nested one belonged to which parent and it gets messy trying to keep track of everything

Comment: Anyway, provide the final array (or rows in DB) you want to get based on your input above)

Comment: @questlooking see my edit?

Answer (score 0):

How about recursive function for saving that:

```
function save_recursive(array $array, int $parentId = null)
{
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        echo "Save '$key' key with parent id (if it is not null) and with needed attributes and get the last insert id (it will be parent id for the next item)\n";
        // $parentId = {last_insert_id};
    
        if (is_array($value)) {
            save_recursive($value, $parentId);
        }
    }
}

save_recursive($array);
```

But in this case you will not be able to save this like one `INSERT` statement (bulk), only one by one.

*Alternatives*: to perform the bulk insert you can try to play with the following scenarios:

- get the current `AUTO_INCREMENT` value from the table and try to increase it manually in recursion function to build one insert query
- use temporary table as copy of existing table with setting `AUTO_INCREMENT` as in a real table. Insert all items into temporary table without `parentId` in one query and than in another query just insert data to real table from temporary with additional sub queries for filling `parentId` column (because you know all ids).

But alternative cases must be checked before. Maybe they are less effective as inserting one by one.

Comment: that's like recursion plus O(n) on each step? though I'm working with loops which go O(n)^2 at most and extract data that I need and then bulk insert it. Though its not complete but I think would be better than recursion with loop?